# Avoiding rounding in convert.tosingle method

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding-error

consider ,

```
object a =1.123456;
float f = convert.ToSingle(a);
```

But when I print the value of f , I get 1.123455.

It is getting rounded off.
Also the problem is I cant change the data type of float in the code.
Please help.

Comment: Notice that when assigning object with a floating-point value - it will be translated to double.
If you want the value to be kept as float - add 'F' in the end of the number (e.g: object a = 1.123456F)

Comment: When I run that code and print the result I get "1.123456" as the output. Using VS2010 and C# 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This is done because of the way the floating-point type works.
If you want a better precision (in the cost of some performance) - use the Double or Decimal type instead.

For more information about why floating-point loses precision, read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s%28VS.80%29.aspx